# How to create an array without knowing how many values will be store?

Tags: c#, arrays, memory, allocation

In C# I'm storing values in an array.

So to create this array I'm using this code, 'int[] values = new int[10];'

But, what if I need more than 10 values, or in the case I never know how many values  I will have. Could be 1, 10 or 100.

I understand the idea that I need to let the compiler know how big the array should be so it can allocate memory space for it.

Is there a way to work around that?

Comment: To avoid this problem, you can use a [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) And then when it ready, use the [List.toArray()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.toarray?view=netframework-4.7.2) function to cast it in array

Comment: If you only have an one dimensional array, why don't you use a list instead to store your values?

Answer (score 3):

You could just use a [`List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) and let it do all the heavy lifting for you:

```
List<int> values = new List<int>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays must have defined length. If you want dynamic size, consider using List class.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at and research the concept of "Immutable objects"

An array has a fixed size, If you need an array with a dynamic size it is best to either create extension methods or a handler that does the work for you.

The work to be done is to get the array, create a new array with the new size based on whether you want to add or remove something, and to populate the new array with the data from the previous array. This will create a new object instead of modifying the previous object and will make sure you don't push items to a full array, or have an array with a size larger than the items that fit in it.

Ofcourse the List class would work as well and would probably solve your problem.